# Measuring interval in pseudo-Euclidean space

Tags: geometry

Suppose we have a 2D pseudo-Euclidean space positioned on a rectangle sheet of paper with one axis parallel to one side and another axis parallel to another side. And we have a line segment drawn on this sheet. Is it possible to measure interval of this line in this pseudo-Euclidean space in a similarly simple way as in case of Euclidean space (using a ruler)? Does one have to measure projections on axes and then use definition of interval in such space? Or is there an easier way?

Comment: The triangle inequality can be false in pseudo-Euclidean spaces, so  terms like length and distance are avoided.

Comment: @DavidH OK, fixed to interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lenght seems a bit [slippery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Euclidean_space#Distance) for pseudo-Euclidean spaces, but for a straight line if you start with the standard definition of *length* of a curve (limit with finer and finer partitions of the parametrising interval) you will get exactly the same as if you were computing *distance* of the endpoints (any sum approximating the limit will have this value).

However you clearly can't just use ruler if the metric is not Euclidean (unless your line is vertical), you *must* use the definition (as usually in maths;) ) - just in the way (with projections) you described.